# how to replace EDI characters in perl to get the desired output

Tags: perl

I want to replace this string:

```
@N9*BM*MSCUMF036299@
```

with:

```
@N9*BM*MF036299@
```

in perl.

I have tried this but it has not worked.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$string = "@N9*BM*MSCUMF036299@";
$string =~ s/"N9.BM.MSCU"/"N9*BM*"/;
print "$string\n";
```

Comment: Please post the code that you've tried and errors that you received.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl
$string = "@N9*BM*MSCUMF036299@";
#print "$string\n\@\*";
$string =~ s/"N9.BM.MSCU"/"N9\*BM\*"/;
print "$string\n";

Comment: Why not just: `s/MSCU//;`?

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried this but it has not worked.
>
> ```
> $string = "@N9*BM*MSCUMF036299@";
> $string =~ s/"N9.BM.MSCU"/"N9*BM*"/;
> ```

Since you used double quotes around the literal string, an undefined array variable `@N9` was interpolated, yielding `$string = "*BM*MSCUMF036299@"`. To avoid that, use single quotes.
Besides that, the quotes in `s/"N9.BM.MSCU"/"N9*BM*"/` are out of place.
Correct:

```
$string = '@N9*BM*MSCUMF036299@';
$string =~ s/N9.BM.MSCU/N9*BM*/;
```